# Is there a short code to apply all media queries in one shot bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Now I use this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2    col-sm-2    col-md-2    col-lg-2">
```

Is there a way to shorten it?

So I don't have to repeat, since all columns will span equally?

Comment: maybe you can use `jquery` to shorten. sample you create `class` like `Myresponsive` then you can use `addclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just set `col-xs-2` only and the width will apply on all screen dimension

Comment: EXACTLY the answer I was looking for. I tried things like   col-*-2    ect...but couldn't get it working!

Comment: @BrunoVincent Great! Glad it helped.

Comment: Additionally, I want a 6 column grid that shrinks and keeps 6 columns on any screen size, how can I do that with bootstrap without ANY media queries, is it possible?

Comment: @BrunoVincent Yes, you can do that. Create 6 `<div class="col-xs-2"></div>` of this.